# From node-semver documentation, what is meaning of symbol "-0" after version

Tags: semantic-versioning

~1.2.3 := >=1.2.3 <1.(2+1).0 := >=1.2.3 <1.3.0**-0**
(highlighted)

In above example, what is the meaning of symbol `-0` after version(`1.3.0-0`)?

see: https://github.com/npm/node-semver#versions

Comment: https://semver.org/ From Item 9, it looks like it's used for a pre-release version. So it seems to be a prerelease tag? I tried using `semver.inc('1.2.3', 'prerelease', '')`, and got `'1.2.4-0'`

Comment: @qrsngky Thanks! `-0` from `1.3.0-0` means very-first pre-release of `1.3.0`. If so, why is it used with the `<` symbol? I don't think it simply means 'every pre-release lower than 1.3.0-0'.

Comment: (Following the comment above) Actually, according to https://semver.npmjs.com/, there is no difference between `>=2.0.0-alpha-3 <6.0.1-0` and `>=2.0.0-alpha-3 <6.0.1`. (I picked a 'npm' package.)

Comment: If you use `semver.satisfies` then there should be no difference: *anything with 1.3.... won't satisfy the requirement*. But if someone uses `semver.gt` and `semver.lt` then '1.3.0-0' results in `semver.gt("1.3.0-0", "1.2.0")`==true and `semver.lt("1.3.0-0", "1.3.0")`==true, i.e. `1.3.0-0` would appear to be both '>1.2.0' and '<1.3.0'. But `semver.satisfies('1.3.0-0', '>1.2.0')` is false anyway.